# Display posts by alphabetical order

Tags: plugins, customization, categories, custom-taxonomy, menus

I just purchased a WordPress theme. I’m trying to sort post on one category into an alphabetical listing (glossary type of listing).

Example : https://www.udiscovermusic.com/browse-artists/

There are using a WordPress theme, I just don’t know how to create that.

I have tried several plugins (like A-Z Listing and others) but it doesn't look good at all.

Could you please help me please ? Do you know a plugin or a way to create this please ?

thank you

Comment: Are you dealing with posts or custom post types? For custom post types, you might need to implement a different logic than for posts.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sort order on a category archive page to show posts by title (A-Z) by adding this code to your child theme's functions.php:

```
/* Sort posts by title for a specific category */
function change_category_order( $query ) {
    //Sort all posts from category with id=3 by title
    if($query->is_category('3') && $query->is_main_query()){
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'name';
        $query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
    } 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_category_order' );
```

You need to replace "3" with the correct category id. You can find out the category id by heading to dashboard => post => categories and hover over the category you want to adjust the sort order.

Comment: hi, there's a problem : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in /home/customer/www/elontrap.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/smart-mag/functions.php on line 80

Comment: I am sorry, i made a typo. Replace the ```elseif``` with ```if```. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks but it doesnt do anything :/

Comment: That is why I asked you if it is a custom post type (e.g. artists instead of posts) and a custom taxonomy (e.g. genres instead of categories). This code should work only for posts from a specific category. For a custom taxonomy, you should use ```is_tax()``` instead of ```is_category```. Let me know and i will update.